# First-principles benchmark of CFD solver

Tags: fluid-dynamics, benchmarking

A decade ago I saw a ~20 coupled state + random number problem that was used as a benchmark for meteorological CFD tools.  It had a fractal dimension (of the chaotic attractor) around 2.3, I think.  I saw matlab code for it.

I'm looking for the method now, and can't remember what it was called.  To be clear it was entirely synthetic.  It was not flow in 2d or 3d.  It wasn't a cylinder, cavity, or other plausible mechanical system.  It was something like 20 nonlinear coupled states, and a random number generator.

Can you help me find this method?  It would be able to differentiate between ensemble Kalman filter or 4dvar in terms of performance, I think.

Comment: This is surely some variant of a Lorenz system. Some googling turned up things like this http://www.environnement.ens.fr/IMG/file/MichaelPDF/CSG-RDS-Physica_D'11.pdf